# Strange behaviour when subclassing AbstractUser

Tags: django, oracle, django-south, django-1.5

I think there is a bug in South. I subclassed AbstractUser in my app and set AUTH_USER_MODEL in settings.py to point to that User class. Upon running `syncdb` without south you can see that some of the fields in user table are nullable:

[image]

But when I enable south and do `schemamigration --initial`, `syncdb` and `migrate` then all of the fields in user table are not nullable:

[image]

This gives me the following error when creating superuser with manage `createsuperuser`:

> IntegrityError: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("TEST"."MYAPP_USER"."FIRST_NAME")

EDIT: Maybe I should mention that I'm using Oracle database.

Comment: do you happen to have any files in the `migrations/` directory of your app ?

Comment: I deleted migrations directory when I tried running syncdb without South. And then migrations dir got created when running schemamigration --initial of course.